# My code is throwing an error on a groupby function I used

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

```
ccmb1_qc_endo_df = read_qc_endotoxin(ccmb1_qc_data_df)
raw_material = "CCMB1"
ccmb1_qc_endo_df[f"{raw_material} Lot"] = ccmb1_qc_endo_df[f"{raw_material} Lot"].astype(str)
ccmb1_qc_endo_df = [[f"{raw_material} Lot", "Avg Endotoxin (EU/kg)",
                   "AVG Osmo mOsm/kg", "AVG Bioburden CFU/mL"]]
ccmb1_qc_endo_df = ccmb1_qc_endo_df.groupby(f"{raw_material} Lot").mean().reset_index()
```

the error code:

```
Job failed: Error in Python process: At line 61: <class 'AttributeError'>: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'. Line 61 i the last line of code for the syntax above
```

I am trying to group by {raw_material} Lot

Comment: Your `ccmb1_qc_endo_df` is no dataframe. It is the list you created in the line before.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Klaus D. mentioned in comment:

```
ccmb1_qc_endo_df = [[f"{raw_material} Lot", "Avg Endotoxin (EU/kg)",
                   "AVG Osmo mOsm/kg", "AVG Bioburden CFU/mL"]]
```

is a nested list instead of dataframe.

thats why you are getting error on:

```
ccmb1_qc_endo_df.groupby(f"{raw_material} Lot").mean().reset_index()

<class 'AttributeError'>: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

Comment: Thanks, Klaus D.

how do I correct this?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the hint, Klaus D.

Comment: @CanthianoProsky.. do you mind accepting the answer if it helped you. You can click the arrow icon